# Mapping by code with Nhibernate 3.2 sqlite blob field with byte[] not working

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sqlite

I have a very simple sqlite database with a blob column in a table images for storaging images, i'm using Nhibernate 3.2 I installed from NuGet and I'm using the new feature of mapping by code, here is the code:

The Package:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
      <package id="Iesi.Collections" version="3.2.0.4000" targetFramework="net40" />
      <package id="NHibernate" version="3.2.0.4000" targetFramework="net40" />
    </packages>
```

The Model Class:

```
using DBAccessLayer.DataAccess;
using NHibernate.Type;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace DBAccessLayer.Models
{
    public class Picture
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Byte[] BytesImage { get; set; }

        public virtual Place Place { get; set; }

        public virtual BitmapImage Image
        {
            get
            {
                return Tools.ParseBlob(BytesImage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Mapper Class:

```
using DBAccessLayer.Models;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist;
using NHibernate.Type;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DBAccessLayer.Mappers
{
    public class PictureMap : ClassMapping<Picture>
    {
        public PictureMap()
    {
            Table("images");
            Id(x => x.Id, m =>
            {
                m.Generator(Generators.Identity);
                m.Column("id");
            });
            Property(x => x.BytesImage, m => { m.Column("image"); });

            ManyToOne(p => p.Place, map => map.Column("place_id"));
    }
    }
}
```

When i run on console with a simple query to retrieve a Picture the next nhibernate parsing error comes out:

**{"Could not cast the value in field image2_ of type Byte[] to the Type BinaryType.  Please check to make sure that the mapping is correct and that your DataProvider supports this Data Type."}**
**{"Specified cast is not valid."}**

I'm using this configuration and it works without mapping the blob fields, so i don't think this is the problem:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory name="NHibernate.Test">
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=datacenter.db;Version=3</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I need to fix this problem, so I can retrieve the image stored in my database, any help appreciated.